# Renaming file in one drive from power automate flow

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

I have a power automate flow which gets an attachment from an email, and creates a new file in OneDrive folder with a new file name.

In my Action to Create a new file in OneDrive, This is what I have so far under the file name parameter:

```
concat('CounterpartyName',formatDateTime(utcNow(),''))
```

this gives me an ouput of this when I look in OneDrive:

```
CounterpartyName-2_23_2024 8_57_24
```

The file is not saved with the same suffix as the original attachment and the date formatting is not what I want.

Since I am working only with .csv, .xls, and .xlsx files this is what my output should look like:

```
CounterpartyName-02Feb24.csv  
OR
CounterpartyName-02Feb24.xls  
OR
CounterpartyName-02Feb24.xlsx
```

I am new to power platform so how could I alter that code to achieve those results? Any suggestions would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this for the date ...

```
concat('CounterpartyName',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'ddMMMyy'))
```

... and as for the file extension, without knowing the name of your file, use a `split()` function with a period as a separator and then wrap that in a `last()` function to get the extension.

Further to that, you can actually do everything without the need for a `concat()` function, like this ...

[image]

**Expression 1** = `formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'ddMMMyy')`

**Expression 2** = `last(split('Original File Name.xlsx', '.'))`

... also notice the period between the two expressions.